# How to keep or properly cast object Type?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Im dealing with this problem.

I have base class `Worker` that is abstract. Its base class for `Driver` and `AmountBonus`. That `Bonus` is writed based on [Decorator design pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator). My decorator decorate one of property from `Worker`.

How it looks in code:

```
public abstract class Worker {}

public class Driver : Worker {}

public abstract class Bonus : Worker 
{
    public Bonus(Worker worker) => this.worker = worker; //constructor
    //decorator on worker's property
}

public class AmountBonus : Bonus 
{
     public AmountBonus(Worker worker) : base(worker: worker){ } //constructor
}
```

Im making `WebApi` app. I operate in data by endpoints. That is my `PUT` request:

```
    // PUT: api/Bonus/Amount/5
    [HttpPut("Amount/{id}")]
    public Worker Get(int id)
    {
        var worker = _context.Workers.Find(id);

        switch (worker)
        {
            case Driver d:
                worker = new AmountBonus(worker) { Id = id };
                //exception here
                _context.Entry((Driver)worker).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _context.SaveChanges();
                break;
        }
        return worker;
    }
```

It is obviious, that i get:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type '....Models.Bonus.AmountBonus' to type '...Models.Driver'.'

But my question is, is it any posibilities to vast that `Driver` object type? I needed it to edit exact same row in my database. My `dbo.Workers` column have column `Discriminator` made by Entity Framework Core and i need to have values like `Driver`, `Farmer` etc that i made and didnt mentioned in this example.

I Could make an Entity for my `AmountBonus` that i said, i need to have origin object type in my database. And i need to use [Decorator](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator) there. Any ideas, how i can do it? Is it possible, to keep origin `Type`?

Comment: You can't cast two different classes even if they inherit the same base class. What you should do is create some flexibility in your base class to allow this, specifically through methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing actual valid worker instance to the decorator.
Make any change, decorator do, to that provided instance.
Then you will be able to save modified instance to the database.

```
[HttpPut("Amount/{id}")]
public Worker Get(int id)
{
    var worker = _context.Workers.Find(id);

    switch (worker)
    {
        case Driver d:
            var amountBonus = new AmountBonus(worker) { Id = id };
            amountBonus.ExecuteDecoration();

            _context.Entry(worker).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            break;
    }

    return Ok(worker);
}
```

`AmountBonus` class does not even need to inherit from `Worker`. Your casting problem goes away itself then
Then it look more like Visitor pattern for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing makes no sense. Decorators are utility classes; they overlay programmatic functionality on to the classes they decorate. They are not something that can nor should be persisted to something like a database.

In other words, if your object is a `Driver`, then you need to keep it a `Driver`, not wrap it in an `AmountBonus` decorator and then attempt to persist *that*. Later, if you need whatever functionality the `AmountBonus` decorator adds again, you simply wrap your `Driver` instance in it again.

It doesn't even look like you're doing anything interesting with the decorator here, but if there is something that occurs just by the act of wrapping a `Driver` instance, then you'll need to fetch out somehow that wrapped `Driver` instance afterwards to actually save *that* and not your decorator.